# AZURE ARM Policy assignments skus

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a policy assignment on my resource group.When assigning the policy i need to pass the skus along with my json request.I have changed everything dynamically. Other then sku information. I need to make sku information dynamic while sending the request. Below is my request in XML format which i converts in json while sending request.

```
<SubscriptionID>XXXXXXXXX</SubscriptionID>
<ClientSecretKey>XXXXXXXXX</ClientSecretKey>
<TenantId>XXXXXXXXX</TenantId>
<NativeClientId>XXXXXXXXX</NativeClientId>
<ResourceGroupname>XXXXXXXX</ResourceGroupname>
<PolicyName>XXXXXXX</PolicyName>
  <assignments>
  <properties>
    <description>This policy audits VMs that do not use managed disks</description>
    <displayName>Audit VMs that do not use managed disks</displayName>
    <parameters/>
    <policyDefinitionId>XXXXXXXX</policyDefinitionId>
    <scope>/XXXXXXXX</scope>
  </properties>
  <sku>
    <name>A1</name>
    <tier>Standard</tier>
  </sku>
</assignments>
```

Comment: Also let me know what is the role of sku while policy assignment

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem.  Your SKU structure looks fine and should be correct when converted to JSON.

SKU does not currently make a difference on policy assignments.  Feel free to use either SKU value (A1 standard or A0 free).